# Custom Define user datatype vb.net - lika double

Tags: .net, vb.net, types

Is there a chance to make a custom defined Datatype like double but with round function included in it.

For example:

```
Dim x, y, z as Double
x = 10
y = 3
z = 10 / 3
Result.>  z = 3.333333
```

How to make a default data type that will round automatically  double value to predefined decimals. But not with functions like z.math or math(z)

like :

```
Dim x,y,z as CustomType
x = 10
y = 3
z = 10 / 3
```

Because we made the Custom datatype and we know that it will round after third decimal and result will be :  z = 3.330

Comment: Is [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) an option? => Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.000}", Math.Round(3.3333333, 2))) = 3.330

Comment: I know this but if u have too much variables in double to make sum math , U need to Write all that code when u (if u can Make) a Custom Double that will do the same thing

Comment: Can you post the code of your custom double class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to use something other than the / symbol, the easiest approach is to define an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) on Double:

```
Module DoubleExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function Div(value1 As Double, value2 As Double) As Double
        Return Math.Round(value1 / value2, 3)
    End Function

End Module
```

This makes your code look like:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim x As Double = 1
    Dim y As Double = 3

    Dim z As Double = x.Div(y)

    Debug.WriteLine(z)
End Sub
```

Otherwise, because you cannot inherit from base data types, you would have to create a class that contains all of the [operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hddt295a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that you need to support.

The problem with this approach is that you then have to declare the values as your new class type and instantiate them. The following is a substantially incomplete example, but illustrates the work you would have to do and the "look" of your code afterward:

```
Public Class MyDouble
    Private m_Double As Double
    Public Sub New(value As Double)
        m_Double = value
    End Sub

    Public Shared Operator =(value1 As MyDouble, value2 As Double) As Double
        value1.Value = value2
        Return value2
    End Operator
    Public Shared Operator <>(value1 As MyDouble, value2 As Double) As Double
        Return value2
    End Operator
    Public Shared Operator /(value1 As MyDouble, value2 As MyDouble) As Double
        Return Math.Round(value1.Value / value2.value, 3)
    End Operator

    Public Property Value As Double
        Get
            Return m_Double
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_Double = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And the resultant code:

```
    Dim x As New MyDouble(1)
    Dim y As New MyDouble(3)

    Dim z As Double = x / y
```